# material icons name display as text in google

Tags: google-search, google-material-icons

When I using google material icons in my site, google show icon name as search title in search resutls

for example

```
<li>
  <a href="contact.htm" ><span>contact us </span><i class="material-icons">email</i></a>
</li>
```

will be: **contac us email**

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, but I removed the pages from Google search results using robot.txt file

Comment: ok. I had found it. Actually the font was not loaded. so add a link in the css file for the font.